# WPF Toolkit - set Line Series polyline color with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpftoolkit

I have added LineSeries in my chart. Here is the code:

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="line" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                <Polyline x:Name="polyline"
              Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" 
              Stroke="Green" 
              Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" />
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
```

This works ok. My polyline is colored in green. But when I try to set Polyline.Stroke color using binding my line becomes invisible. Here is the code:

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="line" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                <Polyline x:Name="polyline"
              Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" 
              Stroke="{Binding Path=MyColor}" 
              Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" />
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
```

I can't figure it out what it seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong type for the color, you should use a `SolidColorBrush`

```
 private SolidColorBrush _chartColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
    public SolidColorBrush ChartColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _chartColor;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_chartColor == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _chartColor = value;
        }
    }
```

then the binding should works perfectly

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart   Title="Line Series"  
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"  >
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="line" ItemsSource="{Binding LineSeriesData}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                        <Polyline x:Name="polyline"
                                  Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" 
                                  Stroke="{Binding ChartColor}" 
                                  Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>

        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Comment: I used SolidColorBrush but its not working... Do you have any other idea?

Comment: the code i gave you works fine for me, make sure your "MyColor" isn't null, or post more of your code so we can't figure out where the problem is !